# Python webapp2 App Engine static images not displaying

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, webapp2

I'm working on a project using python(2.7), webapp2 and App Engine in which I'm trying to display some static images, but bot got that working.

Here's my director structure:

```
|Root
├── bp_content
│   └── themes
│       └── default
│           ├── config
│           ├── handlers
│           ├── routes
│           ├── static
│           │   ├── css
│           │   ├── img
│           │   ├── js
│           │   └── less
│           └── templates
│               ├── emails
│               ├── errors
│               └── seo
|               └── base.html
|               └── home.html
```

and inside the root of my project I have `app.yaml`.

Here's the portion from my `app.yaml`:

```
handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  mime_type: image/vnd.microsoft.icon
  static_files: bp_content/themes/default/static/favicon.ico
  upload: bp_content/themes/default/static/favicon.ico

- url: /(\w*)/favicon\.ico
  mime_type: image/vnd.microsoft.icon
  static_files: bp_content/themes/\1/static/favicon.ico
  upload: bp_content/themes/(\w*)/static/favicon.ico

- url: /(\w*)/(apple-touch-icon.*\.(png))
  static_files: bp_content/themes/\1/static/\2
  upload: bp_content/themes/(\w*)/static/(apple-touch-icon.*\.(png))

- url: /(robots\.txt|humans\.txt|sitemap\.xml|crossdomain\.xml)
  script: main.app

- url: /boilerplate/css
  mime_type: text/css
  static_dir: bp_includes/static/css

- url: /boilerplate/js
  mime_type: text/javascript
  static_dir: bp_includes/static/js

- url: /boilerplate/img/(.*\.(gif|png|jpg))
  static_files: bp_includes/static/img/\1
  upload: bp_includes/static/img/(.*\.(gif|png|jpg))

- url: /(\w*)/css/(.*\.css)$
  mime_type: text/css
  static_files: bp_content/themes/\1/static/css/\2
  upload: bp_content/themes/(\w*)/static/css/(.*\.css)$

- url: /(\w*)/js/(.*\.js)$
  mime_type: text/javascript
  static_files: bp_content/themes/\1/static/js/\2
  upload: bp_content/themes/(\w*)/static/js/(.*\.js)$

- url: /(\w*)/img/(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg))
  static_files: bp_content/themes/\1/static/img/\2
  upload: bp_content/themes/(\w*)/static/img/(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg))

- url: /(\w*)/fonts/(.*\.eot)$
  mime_type: application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  static_files: bp_content/themes/\1/static/fonts/\2
  upload: bp_content/themes/(\w*)/static/fonts/(.*\.eot)

- url: /boilerplate/fonts/(.*\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff))
  static_files: bp_includes/static/fonts/\1
  upload: bp_includes/static/fonts/(.*\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff))

- url: /(\w*)/fonts/(.*\.otf)$
  mime_type: font/opentype
  static_files: bp_content/themes/\1/static/fonts/\2
  upload: bp_content/themes/(\w*)/static/fonts/(.*\.otf)

- url: /(\w*)/fonts/(.*\.ttf)$
  mime_type: application/x-font-ttf
  static_files: bp_content/themes/\1/static/fonts/\2
  upload: bp_content/themes/(\w*)/static/fonts/(.*\.ttf)

- url: /(\w*)/fonts/(.*\.woff)$
  mime_type: application/x-font-woff
  static_files: bp_content/themes/\1/static/fonts/\2
  upload: bp_content/themes/(\w*)/static/fonts/(.*\.woff)

- url: /(\w*)/fonts/(.*\.svg)$
  mime_type: image/svg+xml
  static_files: bp_content/themes/\1/static/fonts/\2
  upload: bp_content/themes/(\w*)/static/fonts/(.*\.svg)

- url: /.*
  script: main.app
```

I have placed an image inside `bp_content -> themes -> default -> static -> img`

and then used it as:

```
<img src="../static/img/teamwork1.jpg" alt="" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your html needs to be like this:

`<img src="/default/img/teamwork1.jpg" alt="" />`

assuming your image is here `/bp_content/themes/default/static/img/teamwork1.jpg`